# How to hide button send if user enter only new lines in EditText android?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

As question said 
I want hide the button send , but when user enter text to edit text I want to show this button , also I want to still hide the button when the user enter only new lines or space , to prevent him to sent empty message

my code

```
 edttext_addcomment_addcomment_popup_dialog.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            IsposthasContent();
        }
    }); 

  private void IsposthasContent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String text = edttext_addcomment_addcomment_popup_dialog.getText().toString();
    if (edttext_addcomment_addcomment_popup_dialog.getText() != null && edttext_addcomment_addcomment_popup_dialog.getText().length()>0) {
        btnaddcommentContainer_addcomment_popup_dialog.setEnabled(true);

    } else {
        btnaddcommentContainer_addcomment_popup_dialog.setEnabled(false);           
    }
}
```

Comment: see my editing in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add textwatcher to edittext. And trim method remove space end. You can examine this code

```
editTextComment.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextComment.getText().toString().trim())) {
               buttonSend.setEnabled(false);
               buttonSend.setAlpha(0.5f);
            }
            else {
               buttonSend.setEnabled(true);
               buttonSend.setAlpha(1f);
            }
         }

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         }
      });
```

Comment: big thanks , I added "TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextComment.getText().toString().trim())" to my condition